# Entitlement are not valid?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

My friend send me Build & provision profile ok, 1st I install provision profile than I upload Build on my i pod device , I face this error. Entitlement are not valid?? could you please tell me how can i solve this problem

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? (please be more specific, these are not self-evident from the current state of your question)

Answer (score 0):

The standard Project template does not include the entitlements file.  On your project, add a new file (File, New).  Select Code Signing as the category under iOS, and pick "Entitlements" template.  You can name the file Entitlements.plist.

Then, on your Target, go to Build Settings, and set your Code Signing Entitlements setting to the name of this new file.

You should be able to build and distribute it just fine now.